# SQL Server 2008 column in only one table

Tags: sql-server-2008, data-mining, sql-scripts

First a quick explanation: I am actually dealing with four tables and mining data from different places but my problem comes down to this seemingly simple concept and yes I am very new to this...

I have two tables (one and two) that both have ID columns in them. I want to query only the ID columns that are in table two only, not in both. As in..

```
Select ID
From dbo.one, dbo.two
Where dbo.two != dbo.one
```

I actually thought this would work but I'm getting odd results. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.ID
    FROM dbo.two t2
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                         FROM dbo.one t1
                         WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID)
```

This could also be done with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t2.ID
    FROM dbo.two t2
        LEFT JOIN dbo.one t1
            ON t2.ID = t1.ID
    WHERE t1.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Works great thanks a bunch! Now I'm off to study this NOT EXISTS clause. Thanks again!

Comment: @2boolORNOT2bool: see my answer on dba.se please http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4009/the-use-of-not-logic-in-relation-to-indexes/4010#4010

Comment: I'm learning that you guys know a great deal more than I expected, I know a great deal less than I expected, and Stack is hugh. Theres a Christianity site! Wow!

Answer (score 2):

Completing the other 2 options after Joe's answer...

```
SELECT id
FROM dbo.two
EXCEPT
SELECT id
FROM dbo.one

SELECT t2.ID
FROM dbo.two t2
WHERE t2.ID NOT IN (SELECT t1.ID FROM dbo.one t1)
```

Note: LEFT JOIN will be slower than the other three, which should all give the same plan.

That's because LEFT JOIN is a join followed by a filter, the other 3 are semi-join

Comment: This looks solid as well. I'll try this out too so I can play with that EXCEPT clause. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Umm.. I ran your query and got different results. I thought I screwed something up so I phisicaly checked the tables and Joes code is just giving me all the IDs in table two. Yours seams to be sorting through. I may have done a pre-imptive strike on the answer check. Or I could very well be doing something wrong.

Comment: @2boolORNOT2bool: any sort is accidental without an ORDER BY